# bring particle emitter in front of a UIButton

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uibutton

Here is a pretty little scene, with a snowy background as well as a centered play button.

How do I get the snow to fall in FRONT (and optionally in front of and also in back of) my button? I cannot seem to mix and match a UIButton with the snow emitter that way. I'd prefer not to make the button into an SKNode if I didn't have to (unless that's the 'proper' way)...

```
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var snowView: SKView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = WelcomeScene(fileNamed:"WelcomeScene") {
        // Configure the view.

        if let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "snow") {
            emitter.position = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.bounds.maxY + 20)
            emitter.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: view.bounds.width + 20, dy: 10)
            emitter.zPosition = 2
            scene.addChild(emitter)
        }

        playButton.layer.cornerRadius = playButton.frame.size.height / 2
        playButton.bringSubviewToFront(snowView)

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        snowView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the `snowView.backgroundColor` to something with transparency?  That _may_ allow the button to appear in the background.  Could you add some more information about what happens?  Does the `snowView` appear in front or behind the button?  Can you change it back and forth?

Comment: Snow view has transparent background. Nonetheless, it always is behind the uibutton. I started to make a sknode button which the snow nicely falls in front of, but that seems like an awful lot of excess work when it's more likely just some property that can be altered to accomplish the same goal it also seems wasteful to put a stack of views on top of each other but maybe that's the way... I'm really looking for best practices here....